# Generar un efecto de etiqueta, al escribir un texto en un input y separa con comas (con css y/o jquery)

Tags: jquery

tengo una consulta, seguro alguno de ustedes ya lo encontró en la web y si me podría dar una ayudita.
Ando buscando un ejemplo que tenga este efecto, no se como explicarlo con palabras XD, asi que adjunto una imagen sobre como quedaría el efecto.

> DETALLE: Al escribir un texto en un input, si separo con una coma las
> palabras se van agrupando en bloques.

[image: efecto etiquetas en input]

Answer (score 0):

justo cuando genere mi pregunta por casualidad encontre la respuesta cuando ingresaba los tags en el input.
[image: input tags]
En caso alguno tenga la misma consulta, aqui dejo un ejemplo de la respuesta:

> http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/